# Is it possible to use $routeProvider and $stateProvder in same .js file

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use `$routeProvider` and `$stateProvder` in same .js file ?

currently using `ng-view` and using `$routeprovider`, what are the things need to keep in mind while we are migrating to `ui-view`.

Comment: Are you seeing an error when you tried to use them both?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, but it will quite odd to use both functionalities isnt it?

example

```
angular.module('test',['ngRoute','ui.router']).config(function($routeProvider , $stateProvder){

//do something here
})
```